# How to resize image to fit DIV jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, web

I have square DIV and large portrait and landscape images.

I need to fit the image in a DIV with the extra part going `overflow:hidden`

For eg. If portrait set width=width of div height:auto

Opposite for Lanscape.

I tried this script but it didn;t work

```
        $('.magic').each(function(){
        if($(this).css('width')>$(this).css('height')){
            $(this).css('height', '300px');
            $(this).css('width', 'auto');                
        }
        else{
            $(this).css('width', '300px');
            $(this).css('height', 'auto');


        }
    });
```

PS Images can't stretch and must scale

Comment: Why don't you use CSS?

Comment: Is .magic a list of images? Otherwise, perhaps try $('.magic img')

Comment: Image size is not known in advance + magic is the class of the images @undefined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use some CSS like this

```
.magic.portrait {
    height: 300px;
    width: auto;
}

.magic.landscape {
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
}
```

and just add a class with your JS

```
$('.magic').each(function(){
    if($(this).width() > $(this).height()){
        $(this).addClass('landscape');
    }else{
        $(this).addClass('portrait');
    }
});
```

This also helps keep your application logic and styles nicely separated. Even better, add these classes server side, and avoid the JavaScript altogether.

Comment: Edited to remove the string != number issue

Comment: @Fresheyeball it was wrong, I edited it after the enlightenment of jfriend00's answer

Comment: @Fresheyeball - the answer was edited to fix the problem in response to my comment.  You can look at the edit history.  It used to have `if($(this).css('width')>$(this).css('height'))` which is a string comparison, not a numeric comparison.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want a javascript/jquery solution, have a look at [jQuery AnyStretch](https://github.com/danmillar/jquery-anystretch) plugin. It just does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If image sizes are known in advance, you could do this all with CSS.

If you decide you must use javascript, then the problem with your current code is that `$(this).css('width')` retrieves a string like `"300px"`, not a number thus the comparison of two strings doesn't work properly like you would expect a numeric comparison to work.

You can either convert it to a number or you can just use `$(this).width()` which returns a number in pixels.

Working example:

```
$('.magic').each(function(){
    var self = $(this);
    var width = self.width();
    var height = self.height();
    if (width > height) {
        self.css({height: "300px", width: "auto"});
    } else {
        self.css({width: "300px", height: "auto"});
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/B7hVp/